# Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient reusability

Tags: windows, winrt-xaml, uwp

I'm writing a WinStore-XAML app where networking is involved. I know that in Windows store apps the intended class for making Http request is Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient. My question is:

1. Can I reuse an instance of this class for multiple requests? i.e. is this class thread-safe?
2. Suppose the No.1 is true. If I am also using an IoC container in the app, would it be a good practice to register this class as a singleton?

Comment: [Documentation says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) "An HttpClient instance is a collection of settings that apply to all requests executed by that instance." So multiple requests can be executed by a single instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can resuse `HttpClient` and in fact that is the recommended way to use it, from the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/HttpClient/cs/HttpClient/Scenario1_GetText.xaml.cs):

> // In general, for best memory utilization, HttpBaseProtocolFilter and HttpClient objects should be reused for multiple requests.